# What is the difference between assignment statement with echo statement in bash with multi command in oneline

Tags: bash

I have two test snippet code, as follows:

```
# snippet code1
a=100 b=200                   # this line confuses me
echo $a                       # print "100"
```

```
# snippet code2
a=100 echo "sth else"         # this line confuses me
echo $a                       # print empty line
```

What is the difference? How to explain?

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is multiple [assignment statements](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) on the same line; it's the same as

```sh
a=100
b=100
echo "$a
```

The second one is [setting the environment](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Environment) for the command that follows; for example:

```
$ unset a
$ a=abc env | grep -w a
a=abc
$ declare -p a
-bash: declare: a: not found
```

The environment is set for just the command that follows.

Notice that

```sh
a=abc echo "$a"
```

doesn't work because the variable is [expanded before the command is run](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56449/118235).